# Relationship between the solution to $Ax=b$ and $(A+I)x=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have have a symmetric, tridiagonal, Toeplitz matrix $A$, where $A_{11} = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $A_{21} = 1$, and I need to solve the system 
$$
(A+I)x=b,
$$
numerically where $b$ does not necessarily have any special structure.  I would like to try to solve the above problem by solving
$$
Ax = \hat{b},
$$
numerically for an appropriate $\hat{b}$ instead, and using the solution to the second problem to get the solution to the first.

The reason I am doing this is because I have to solve the problem $$ (A + \alpha I)x = b $$ a large number of times for different values of $\alpha$.  If I could solve $Ax=b$ once and then use this solution with a bit of algebra to get the solution for any $\alpha$, my code would probably be much faster.

*Attempt at solution:*

Since $A$ is symmetric positive definite, we have the decomposition $A = Q\Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ is unitary.  Let $\hat{x}$ satisfy $A\hat{x}=b$.  Then $Q(I+\Lambda)Q^T = A+I$ so that (assuming scaling on $A$)
\begin{multline}
x = Q(I+\Lambda)^{-1}Q^Tb = Q(I + \Lambda + \Lambda^2 + \Lambda^3 + \cdots)Q^Tb \\
= b + Ab + A^2b + A^3b + \cdots = A(\hat{x} + A\hat{x} + A^2\hat{x} + \cdots).
\end{multline}
As you might imagine, this doesn't help very much!

Comment: Your matrix $A$ is invertible!

Comment: Hi, if this is possible I would need to solve $Ax=b$ numerically because $A$ is around 500x500, so I can't directly use the invertibility of $A$.  The eigenvectors do follow a nice pattern, but I'm not sure how I can take advantage of this!

Comment: It is a linear system of equations and most computer algebra systems can solve it.

Comment: The point is to solve it very quickly.  I can easily solve this using Thomas' algorithm, but the goal is to do it as quickly as possible.

Comment: In general, different $\alpha$ will lead to different solutions in *all* $n$ components so the update of the solution takes at least $n$ steps. The $LDL^T$ factorization of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix (or the Thomas algorithm) has $O(n)$ complexity. How much faster would you like to be?

Answer (score 0):

Since your matrix $A$ is Toeplitz then you should check [Levinson recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion) .